# Using Cheerio to extract data from a page.. The format is as below. How do I parse these tables dynamically as they can vary?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, cheerio

I hope someone smart can help me get my head around all this arrays and objects and loops.....I've been coming across them alot and I just dont get why there isnt an easy way for me to select on the DOM what I want to scrape and then say export to JS variable as JSON object.

All I am trying to do here is export to a JSON string in this format.

Created th : Created td
Client th : Client td
Owner th : Owner td

Thats what is extract from table ONE

Table TWO is more complicated:

there can be unlimited trs here......this is where I need a loop to ensure all of the text content is put from JS into JSON.

Title th
Content th
Statement th:
Date Description Cost Payment Balance.....all of these rows here can be unlimited.
th and tds are clear but there can be unlimited number of trs

Each title has a content (for Content value just join all the values in the divs).
Each title also has a statement which can have multiple rows.  Its variable.

So columns in the table and in the page wont change but the rows for the second table and the mini statement can change.  The data in the first table is static.

I hope could this of a quick loop to parse this into a JSON object so I can post to my DB?

```
<table class="summary">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Owner</th>
                        <th>Ref</th>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>Postal Address</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Created</td>
                        <td>Client</td>
                        <td>Owner</td>
                        <td>Ref</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Postal Address</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <hr>
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Content</th>
                        <th>Statement</th>
                    </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="packageTitle" onclick="openPackageDetail(&quot;&quot;)" title="Click for detail">{TITLE}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {CONTENT1}
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="lighter smaller">Containing:</div>
                                                    <div>
                                                                <div class="smaller">
                                                                    Early Bird Guest (1)
                                                                </div>

                                                    </div>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table class="smaller statement">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th style="padding-right:1em">Cost</th>
                                            <th style="padding-right:1em">Payment</th>
                                            <th>Balance</th>
                                        </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>dATE AND TIME</td>
                                                    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                                                    <td>COST</td>
                                                    <td>PAYMENT</td>
                                                    <td>BALANCE</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>DATE</td>
                                                    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                                                    <td>COST</td>
                                                    <td>PAYMENT</td>
                                                    <td>BALANCE</td>
                                                    </tr>

                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>

            </tbody></table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but here's a recursive approach to get you started:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<Your HTML copy-pasted from question>`;

const parseTables = root => {
  const headers = [...$(root).find("> tbody > tr > th")].map(
    th => $(th).text().trim()
  );
  return [...$(root).find("> tbody > tr:has(td)")].map(tr =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      [...$(tr).find("> td")].map((td, i) => {
        if ($(td).find("> table").length === 1) {
          return [
            headers[i],
            parseTables($(td).find("> table").get(0)),
          ];
        }

        return [headers[i], $(td).text().trim()];
      })
    )
  );
};

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = [...$("body > table")].map(parseTables);

require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```js
[
  [
    {
      Created: 'Created',
      Client: 'Client',
      Owner: 'Owner',
      Ref: 'Ref',
      'Email Address': 'Email',
      'Postal Address': 'Postal Address'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      Title: '{TITLE}',
      Content: '{CONTENT1}\n' +
        '          Containing:\n' +
        '          \n' +
        '            Early Bird Guest (1)',
      Statement: [
        {
          Date: 'dATE AND TIME',
          Description: 'DESCRIPTION',
          Cost: 'COST',
          Payment: 'PAYMENT',
          Balance: 'BALANCE'
        },
        {
          Date: 'DATE',
          Description: 'DESCRIPTION',
          Cost: 'COST',
          Payment: 'PAYMENT',
          Balance: 'BALANCE'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

This works by doing a fairly normal table scrape, but testing whether a `<td>` has a `<table>` inside of it, and if so, dipping into that table. It doesn't handle cases when there are multiple tables inside of tables--left as an exercise, since it may not apply to your use case.

Note that the "content" element has some sub-HTML that could use parsing as well, so you could handle that in a similar way as sub tables are handled, if you want.